# ASP.NET MVC Bad Practices: Optional Submodel With Required Property (EF6 domain model)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, fortify

I have the following finding received from Fortify on Demand:

ASP.NET MVC Bad Practices: Optional Submodel With Required Property.

I use Entity Framework 6 in my project.

Here is a sample example of the code snippet that received the finding:

```
public class EarningItem
{
   public virtual LookupType LookupType { get; set; }
}

public class LookupType
{
   public LookupType()
   {
      EmailTemplates = new List<EmailTemplate>();
   }

   [Required]
   [ForeignKey("Id")]
   public ICollection<EmailTemplate> EmailTemplates { get; set; }
}

public class EmailTemplate
{
   public EmailTemplate()
   {
      LookupTypes = new List<LookupType>();
   }

   public int Id { get; set; }
   public ICollection<LookupType> LookupTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Here is Entity Type Configuration:

```
public class LookupTypeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<LookupType>
{
   HasMany(g => g.EmailTemplates)
      .WithMany(c => c.LookupTypes)
}
```

Can I remove `[Required]` attribute to get rid of this finding?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well, it doesn't make sense to mark a collection as required. It's not a way to guarantee that it has items.

Comment: @GertArnold So, can I just remove `[Required]` attribute?

Comment: I'd even say: you must. It's only confusing.